# kqueue() and O_NONBLOCK

Tags: io, kqueue

If you use kqueue(), should you set O_NONBLOCK on your file descriptors?  In other words, does kqueue() guarantee that the next I/O operation on a ready file descriptor will not block, regardless of whether O_NONBLOCK is set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you use kqueue(), should you set O_NONBLOCK on your file descriptors?

Nope.

> In other words, does kqueue() guarantee that the next I/O operation on a ready file descriptor will not block, regardless of whether O_NONBLOCK is set?

Yep.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to.  However, I generally do as a sanity check.  This makes operations like read() return -1 and set errno to EWOULDBLOCK.  I would much rather get an EWOULDBLOCK and know that my implementation of kqueue is buggy than have read() calls block (and therefore my program freeze) for unknown reasons.